# Get the scope role for each employee

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query, for each employee I get the list of his different roles :

```
SELECT e.EmployeeId,r.EntityRoleId, r.Label,er.ValueId
FROM Employee e
LEFT JOIN Employee_Role er ON e.EmployeeId = er.EmployeeId
LEFT JOIN [Function].[Role] r ON er.RoleId = r.EntityRoleId
WHERE e.EmployeeId=54
```

This is an extract of the previous query output :
[image]

I want to get the scope for each label (role) of any employee (here the EmployeeId=54) :

The logic behind **ValueId**:

[image]

- NULL means that we don’t care about the scope because your Role is
  Global (not scoped on a specific Entity)
- 2 in the dbo.Employee_Department table matches “DNA” product.
- 1 in the dbo.Employee_Department table matches “Software Factory”
  department.

Which means that : a role can be linked to any entity in the DB (cf. [SchemaName], [TableName], [ColumnName] columns in [Function].[Role])
In Employee_Role, ValueId matches the PK of the table specified in [Function].[Role].

So to get the label of the role RoleId = 250  for EmployeeId = 5255, get the ValueId=2 and look into the table Product with the Schema HoA and get the record having the PrimaryKey(can change from a table to another) =ValueId = 2, the corresponding Label column matches the Role label as below :
[image]

My question is how to get the label of each role in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use a dynamic query, I will need the PK column, but I dont see a location that you are storing the PK column name, for any of the tables used, so I will assume you will need to find it, and for the tables used in RolesEntity the PK is only one column of type Int.

I will use the below T-sql to find out the dynamic sql query needed to be executed:

```
select 'Select '+isnull(er.ColumnName,'*')+' from '+er.SchemaName+'.'+er.TableName+' where '+kcu.COLUMN_NAME+'='+CAST(@ValueId as varchar(10)) from EntityRole er 
        left outer join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc on 
            tc.TABLE_NAME=er.TableName and tc.TABLE_SCHEMA=er.SchemaName
        left outer join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE kcu on kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME=tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    where er.EntityRoleId=250
```

so this will generate the below:-

```
Select Label from HoA.Product where ProductId=2
```

so I will put that in a variable and execute it, then will take the output and return it in the function.